# Turning a link into a div tag block element instead

Tags: html, css

In this code I want to change the the **middle block element** to a **div tag element** **instead** of a link. How do I achieve this result?

All of these are links, I only want to change the middle one to a div block element. I want to turn it into a div block element so I can do something else with it that doesn't involve a link.

It's asking me to provide more details But that pretty much sums up what I'm trying to achieve here.

Is there someone on here who can help me do this? All help would be appreciated.

Middle Block:

[image]

```html
    <style>
      .cover {
        width: 260px;
        height: 168px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-image: linear-gradient( to right, transparent, transparent 83px, #0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px, transparent 260px), url("https://i.imgur.com/BBYxKcf.jpg");
        border: 3px solid #0059dd;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #0059dd;
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .links div {
        margin: 0 0 12px 0;
      }
      
      .links a {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
        transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
      }
      
      .preventWrapping {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      
      .links a:hover,
      .links a:active,
      .links a:focus {
        background: blue;
      }
      
      .scrl a:visited {
        background: orange;
        color: #000000;
      }
      
      .scrl a:hover {
        background: red;
      }
      
      .hide {
        display: none;
      }
      
      .links div:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      
      .test a {
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      
      .controls {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
      }
    
    </style>
     
    <div class="cover hide ">Links</div>
    
    <div class="test">
      <div class="links">
    
        <div class="preventWrapping ">
      
          <div>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
          </div>
    
          <div>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
          </div>
    
          <div>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
            <a href="" target="_blank"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
      
    
    
    
    
    <script>
      (function iife() {
        "use strict";
    
        function hideClickedElement(evt) {
          var target = evt.target;
          target.classList.add("hide");
          document.querySelector(".test").classList.remove("hide");
        }
        var cover = document.querySelector(".cover");
        cover.addEventListener("click", hideClickedElement, false);
      }());
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Ummm... what middle block element are you referring to? And why are you trying to achieve this? That might help in figuring out an answer

Comment: You can disable the link with JavaScript as opposed to changing an anchor link element to a divider. You need to provide your HTML if you'd like an example of how you can achieve that.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://codepen.io/chroline/pen/jamvrb)?